# duplicated values in SQL code

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have the below SQL code -

```
 select distinct opr,  
  CASE
          WHEN timestamp like '201302%' THEN ((SUM (charge / POWER (10, decimals)) OVER (PARTITION BY opr) * 1.15306))
          WHEN timestamp like '201303%' THEN ((SUM (charge / POWER (10, decimals)) OVER (PARTITION BY opr)* 1.14979))
          ELSE 0
       END as exr
  FROM in
group by opr, timestamp, (charge / POWER (10, decimals))
```

**and I expect to receive the value - 1080.104079**

[image]

**However, it gives me two values -**

[image]

**This value 1079.459992 is get, because the exr has been swept, which is wrong, as the charge for 'Feb' should be multiplied on exr for 'Feb'**

[image]

Could you please help me to correct the code, so that I can receive only true value, which is 1080.104079.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is one result, you could try moving the CASE logic into the SUM function itself:

```
select opr,  
    SUM(CASE
          WHEN timestamp like '201302%' THEN ((charge / POWER (10, decimals)) * 1.15306)
          WHEN timestamp like '201303%' THEN ((charge / POWER (10, decimals)) * 1.14979)
          ELSE 0
       END)
       as exr
  FROM in
group by opr
having opr = 'DOM';
```

Part of the problem seems to be that you're grouping by multiple columns, yet selecting only one or two. If you group by the opr column only, you should only get one row for 'DOM'.